# Spikes in openMp run time

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I am comparing the run time of a sequential c program that computes the norm of a matrix to that of one using multithreading with openMp. I have produced the following graph from my result, which are generally as you would expect,but I am unsure what has produced the spikes in the program, with some of the programs taking 20 times as long as expected to complete. Is this purely down to the overhead of producing the multiple threads? If so why is the overhead sometimes so much more than other times?
[image: Revised Graph of time to compute norm of a matrix]

```
void matrix_norm(int n, double *z, double *norm){
    struct timeval tv1, tv2;
    struct timezone tz;
    int i, j;
    *norm = DBL_MAX*(-1.); 

    gettimeofday(&tv1, &tz);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        double row_sum = 0.;
        #pragma omp parallel 
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            row_sum += z[i*n+j];
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            if(row_sum>*norm){
                *norm = row_sum;
            }
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&tv2, &tz);
    double elapsed = (double) (tv2.tv_sec-tv1.tv_sec) + (double) (tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec) * 1.e-6;
    printf("%d %f\n",n, elapsed);
}
```

Here is the result using Z boson's solution

[image: Revised Graph of time to compute norm of a matrix]

Comment: I don't really know what you're doing here, e.g. `temp` doesn't even seem to be defined. Anyway, you might start looking first at the critical section you placed inside the outer loop, why? Keep everything private as long as possible, put the critical section outside the loop. Typically this kind of thing can be done with a reduction clause.

Comment: Your code was a bit ambiguous. Does my solution do what your want?  Did my solution fix your spikes? If so, can you update your plot (I like plots).

Comment: @Zboson It did for the most part, thanks. Definitely improved the performance and reduced the amount and size of spikes in run time.

Comment: @user2644013, I did not mean to replace the plot. You should include the before and after plots.

Comment: I'm a little surprised you see so much of an improvement. This operations should be memory bandwidth bound so the most I would expect is about a factor of two using multiple threads.

Comment: as mentioned, please update your question, now it's not clear what code corresponds to which plot. Also, with such small walltimes I think you'll be affected by other things running on the system.

Comment: Are the reported times from a single run with a given matrix size or are they averages over at least 10 runs with the outliers removed? The spikes are most likely result of OS jitter and since your computation takes on the order of several milliseconds, the jitter introduces relatively huge delays. Also, do not forget to enable OpenMP thread binding and to kill all other CPU-intensive processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following function

```
void matrix_norm(int n, double *z, double *norm){
    int i, j;
    double dtime, temp;
    temp = DBL_MIN;
    dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for private(j) reduction(max:temp)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        double row_sum = 0.;
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            row_sum += z[i*n+j];
        if(row_sum>temp) {
            temp = row_sum;
        }
    }
    *norm = temp;
    dtime += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("%d %f\n",n, dtime);
}
```